# Cannot execute more than 1 function call

Tags: r

**The Code:**

```
{      
  print("df=5")
  qt(p=0.4, df=5, lower.tail=FALSE)
  
  print("df=10")
  qt(p=0.4, df=10, lower.tail=FALSE)
  
  print("df=40")
  qt(p=0.4, df=40, lower.tail=FALSE)
  
  print("df=120")
  qt(p=0.4, df=120, lower.tail=FALSE)
}
```

**Results:**

```
> source('~/test.R', echo=TRUE)

> {
+   print("df=5")
+   qt(p=0.4, df=5, lower .... [TRUNCATED] 
[1] "df=5"
[1] "df=10"
[1] "df=40"
[1] "df=120"
[1] 0.2539095
>
```

Why is it only printing the results of `qt(p=0.4, df=120, lower.tail=FALSE)`? And not the other `qt` function calls?

Comment: Put a print around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R treats everything as a function and always returns the last value, whether you use return or not. For example

```
{      
  print("df=5")
  qt(p=0.4, df=5, lower.tail=FALSE)
  
  print("df=10")
  qt(p=0.4, df=10, lower.tail=FALSE)
  
  print("df=40")
  qt(p=0.4, df=40, lower.tail=FALSE)
  
  print("df=120")
  qt(p=0.4, df=120, lower.tail=FALSE)

  1
}
```

will print all the prints and then will return 1 at the end.
To print all the qt's put a print around each qt call.

Answer (score 1):

None of the `qt` lines are printed. What get printed is the value of the whole expression `{...}`. This will make it clearer to you:

```
> x <- {      
+     print("df=5")
+     qt(p=0.4, df=5, lower.tail=FALSE)
+     
+     print("df=10")
+     qt(p=0.4, df=10, lower.tail=FALSE)
+     
+     print("df=40")
+     qt(p=0.4, df=40, lower.tail=FALSE)
+     
+     print("df=120")
+     qt(p=0.4, df=120, lower.tail=FALSE)
+ }
[1] "df=5"
[1] "df=10"
[1] "df=40"
[1] "df=120"
> 
> print(x)
[1] 0.2539095
```